# Windows can't install Ubuntu AppxBundle package even from Microsoft store

Tags: windows, powershell, ubuntu

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my windows but I keep getting error.
I try downloading from Microsoft store but i got an error "

```
    Error: Something unexpected happened" 
    with error code: 0x80080204
```

I try installing an already downloaded AppxBundle package through PowerShell but i got another error with the same error code

i ran the following code in Powershell as an administrator

```
 Add-AppxPackage -Path "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Ubuntu2204-221101.AppxBundle"
```

I got the following output errors with error codes

```
 Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80080204, The Appx package's manifest is invalid.
 error 0xC00CE015: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 22, Column            96, Note: The schema for MaxVersionTested specified does not recognize XML fields with namespace
 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/10". Please ensure that you have the correct         MaxVersionTested specified. Reason: The attribute
 '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/10}Parameters' on the element       '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/window
  error 0xC00CE015: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 22, Column 96, Note: The schema for MaxVersionTested specified does not recognize XML fields with namespace
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/10". Please ensure that you have the correct       MaxVersionTested specified. Reason: The attribute
 '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/10}Parameters' on the element   '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Application' is not defined in the DTD/Schema.
  NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] c27d6ca4-80d1-0003-23a4-7dc2d180d901 in the Event Log  or use the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID c27d6ca4-80d1-0003-23a4-7dc2d180d901
   At line:1 char:1
   + Add-AppxPackage -Path "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Ubuntu2204-221101.Appx ...
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Users\user\D...1101.AppxBundle:String) [Add-AppxPackage],  Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

I have tried resetting Microsoft store
Windows subsystem for linux is enabled
I have tried troubleshooting
I have restarted the system couple of times
I have equally stop and restart Delivery Optimization
I have checked all the valid boxes in Programs and features
I have done couple of scans and restore through cmd.exe
I have done alot more

```
 wsl --install (did not work either)
```

I am current using the folowing version of windows
Windows 10 Pro
version 1909
build 18363.1256

I was expecting Ubuntu to download and launch normally

Comment: You have schema issue (not an installation issue).  Did you read the exception and check the event logs or use Get-AppPackageLog?

Comment: pls how do i resolve it?

Comment: Following instructions in the exception.  Post any additional error info you find when checking the logs and using Get-AppPackageLog.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I appreciate it. But I am good now the issue is resolved and I have put it down as an answer. Once again thank you

Answer (score 0):

After checking for updates and updating my Windows it didn't work, I decided to upgrade my Windows
from Windows 10 Pro version 1909
to Windows 10 Pro version 22H2

I did this by

1. Provide an empty USB of 16GB size
2. downloading the MediaCreationtool22H2.exe file, install

I installed and run the file, followed the instructions, and download the Windows update directly to the USB Drive (pls, make sure the USB is empty), the download size is about 4GB.

After downloading go inside the USB and run the set up.exe file follow its instructions and be patient as your system will restart several times (make sure your battery is strong and fully charged or you are close to a power  supply).

After the whole process is done, proceed to install the AppxBundle package .

It worked for me, I hope you will find this helpful too. Good luck